# Why did George lie to Shaun and Julian?

Tags: servant

In the fourth season of the show *Servant*, the cultist George tells Julian and Shaun that Leanne does *not* have any magical powers, but rather simply *believes* herself to have them and came up with various convoluted schemes to deceive the family.

Of course, this explanation is false, as evidenced not just by a variety of blatantly supernatural events—though not mentioned on the show, on one occasion Jericho even turned from a doll to a baby while Shaun was *holding him*—but by George's own admission after the fact that he had lied, and the elaborate lengths that even the most high-ranking cult members resorted to in order to try to kill her.

However, *why* did George lie? Shaun and Julian had indicated that they *already* were convinced that Leanne had supernatural abilities, so it was not for plausibility. Perhaps believing that she did not have powers would make them less afraid to act against Leanne, but then again, it might also make them less cautious or even less willing to do what he asked: delivering a fallen angel to a (self-declared) servant of God might seem more appealing than delivering a mentally unstable young woman to a creepy cult leader.

Why, then, did George lie to them?